# HAML select helper not ordering options correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

I'm trying to get some forms out, but I'm having trouble, in that HAML is not ordering the options in my select elements properly.

Here is my echo statement:

```
=select 'user', @empty_data, {"Less than $40k" => 1, "$40k - $70k" => 2, "$70k - $100k" => 3, "$100k+" => 4, "No Thanks" => 5 }
```

However, when the HTML gets rendered, the options are not in any discernible order, let alone the order I placed them in.  Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the list of option is a list of list. Not a Hash

```
=select 'user', @empty_data, [["Less than $40k", 1], ["$40k - $70k",2], ["$70k - $100k",3], ["$100k+",4], ["No Thanks",5]]
```

See the documentation about this helper :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002302

Comment: Why do I get this error?
$ haml --version
Haml 3.1.7 (Separated Sally)
$ haml --trace test.haml out.html
test.haml:14:in `select': wrong argument type String (expected Array) (TypeError)
 from test.haml:14:in `to_html'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.7/bin/../lib/haml/engine.rb:181:in `to_html'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.7/bin/../lib/haml/engine.rb:181:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.7/bin/../lib/haml/engine.rb:181:in `to_html'
...